# Parent container has overflow: auto, but the children height still change when the screen height change

Tags: css

I set the parent container to be `overflow: auto; position: fixed;`. Its direct children is also a container for other elements. I set the height of the direct children to the default `height: auto`. When I decrease the viewport height, instead of having a scroll bar on the parent container, the direct children just start shrinking and the grandchildren elements are gone. Does anyone know what's happening and how to fix it? Would be great if the solution doesn't require a fixed height.

```html
<div class="parent" style="overflow: auto; position: fixed;">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="grandchildren" style="height: 30px;">Div1</div>
    <div class="grandchildren" style="height: 30px;">Div 2</div>
    <div class="grandchildren" style="height: 30px;">Div 3</div>
    <div class="grandchildren" style="height: 30px;">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code snippet on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j67shi/smag4e0u/11/

Comment: As I see the code works fine. if you want scroll bar for your div then check the below snippet. I have posted an example with fixed height to show yo the scroll on div

Comment: @SaiManoj Sorry, I was missing some condition on my code. This is the new snippet https://jsfiddle.net/j67shi/smag4e0u/11/

Comment: Please check the snippet. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

check the below snippet. You need to set height for your parent div

```html
<div class="parent" style="overflow: auto; position: fixed;height:100%">
  <div class="children" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="grandchildren">1</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">2</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">3</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">4</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">5</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">6</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">7</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">8</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">9</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">10</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">11</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">12</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">13</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">14</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">5</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">6</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">7</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">8</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">9</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">10</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">11</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">12</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">13</div>
    <div class="grandchildren">14</div>
  </div>
</div>
```